# Hazelcast Json object querying

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'M storing these JSON Objects the hazelcast

```
IMap<String, HazelcastJsonValue> hazelcast = instance.getMap("get");
```

JSON thta I'm storing

```
{"id":"01","name":"abc","age":33}   

{"id":"02","name":" data","age":37} 

{"id":"03","name":"abc","age":39}
```

if i just want to select only age field with above 35
output:-

```
[37,39]
```

How to do this using projetions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me:

```java
import com.hazelcast.core.*;
import com.hazelcast.projection.Projections;
import com.hazelcast.query.Predicates;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Collection;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

[...]

@Test
public void testJsonProjection() {
  HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
  IMap<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> map = instance.getMap("myMap");

  map.set(0, new HazelcastJsonValue("{\"id\":\"01\",\"name\":\"abc\",\"age\":33}"));
  map.set(1, new HazelcastJsonValue("{\"id\":\"02\",\"name\":\" data\",\"age\":37} "));
  map.set(2, new HazelcastJsonValue("{\"id\":\"03\",\"name\":\"abc\",\"age\":39}"));

  Collection<Long> projection = map.project(
    Projections.singleAttribute("age"),
    Predicates.greaterEqual("age", 35)
  );

  assertThat(projection, containsInAnyOrder(37L, 39L));
}
```

Comment: just a minor comment: If you have a large quantity of documents (let's say more than a few thousands) then perhaps you want to create an index on the age field. 

The index will cost your some memory, but the query is going to be much faster. Without the index Hazelcast has to scan all entries stored.

Creating an index is a simple MapConfig option.